# Need an explanation of the recursive calls in "Towers of Hanoi"

Tags: c, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I understand the concept of recursion and how it stacks up with each call. But I fail to explain how recursive calls are working and gets printed when there are two function call separated by a printf command. Can anyone explain to me how this recursive call is working?

I have found an example regarding a game called "Towers of Hanoi". Ut was used as an example of recursion. The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transfer(int n, char from, char to, char temp);

int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("how many disk");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");
    transfer(n, 'L', 'R', 'C');
    return 0;
}

/*
 * n = number of disk,
 * from = origin,
 * to = destination,
 * temp = temporary storage
 */
void transfer(int n, char from, char to, char temp)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        // Move n-1 disks from origin to temporary
        transfer(n - 1, from, temp, to);

        // Move n th disk from origin to destination
        printf("move disk %d from %c to %c\n", n, from, to);

        // Move n-1 disks from temporary to destination
        transfer(n - 1, temp, to, from);
    }
}
```

for `n=3` it gives output like this

```
move disk 1 from L to R //
move disk 2 from L to C // 
move disk 1 from R to C // 
move disk 3 from L to R // 
move disk 1 form C to L // 
move disk 2 from C to R //
move disk 1 from L to R //
```

Comment: Draw it out step by step with a small number of disks (<=4). The only hard part of understanding ToH recursion is the *pegs* alternating in the call stack. And regarding the printing, the fore and aft recursive calls don't change what `n`, `to`, `from`, and `temp` are in the *current* frame. And to be honest, there are much simpler examples of recursion to get one's head wrapped around than ToH.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this post](https://phoxis.org/2012/03/22/towers_of_hanoi_r/) to answer exactly such a question, which I believe a significant number of beginners face.

What happens is When you have `n` disks.

Task is move n disks from `L` to `R` through `T` , which can be broken down to:

1. Move the top `n-1` disks from `L` to `T`
2. Move the bottom disk from `L` to `R`
3. Move the `n-1` disks from `T` to `R`

Now note that the step 1 and 3 are itself a Towers of Hanoi problem with `n-1` disks and different source and destination poles. The step 1 is a problem to move n-1 disks from `L` to `T` through `R` and step 2 is a problem to move `n-1` disks from `T` to `R` through `L`.

Thus the problem is broken down to sub-problems which can be solved in one step, which is a 2 disk problem instance.

1. Move top disk from `L` to `T`
2. Move bottom disk from `L` to `R`
3. Move top disk from `T` to `R`

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of recursion in a special variant called "end-recursive" !?
The tower of hanoi algorithm is NOT end-recursive. Instead it uses recursion even twice:

1. Move N-1 disks above disk N to temporary stack (1st transfer() function call)
2. move disk N to destination stack (printf)
3. Move back the N-1 disks from temporary stack to destination bove disk N (2nd transfer() function call)

The idea behind the transfer() function recursion is: If it is called with n>1 disks to operate on, it delegates 'work' to recursive invocations of itself. If called with n==1 it just moves the disk.

Here is a modified version which should make things clearer:

```
void transfer(int n, char from, char to, char temp)
{
    if (n > 1) {
        // Move n-1 disks from origin to temporary
        transfer(n - 1, from, temp, to);
    }

    // Move n th disk from origin to destination
    printf("move disk %d from %c to %c\n", n, from, to);

    if (n > 1) {
        // Move n-1 disks from temporary to destination
        transfer(n - 1, temp, to, from);
    }
}
```